# Google Sheets formula to format substrings of column concatenation?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, formatting

If I have a spreadsheet with columns for author, year, title, publication, etc, could I add a column that concatenates *and* formats those as a citation for a bibliography?

It would be something like the following, where `ITALIC` is a function that I wish exists (`BOLD` is not shown, but would also be added for a column of volume numbers):

```
=A2&" ("&B2&"). “"&C2&"”. "&ITALIC(D2)&". "
```

Which would output:

> Jones Jr, Henry (1938). “Archeology Is the Search for Fact”. *Marshall College Monthly*.

Answer (score 1):

No spreadsheet formula can change the *text format* of a cell. Formulas can only return *values* to cells.

To concatenate partially formatted text, you will need a script.

See the [formatText](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/157400260?msgid=157852265) script for sample code.